# Grav Form plugin error

Tags: forms, grav

I have implemented a form to register email of user so we can send them update.

The form works perfectly on integration but without reason fails in production.

When I tried to send the message I get a 500 post error with the following informations :

```
{error: {type: "Whoops\Exception\ErrorException", message: "Undefined index: type",…}}
error : {type: "Whoops\Exception\ErrorException", message: "Undefined index: type" , …}
file : "/var/www/20170803_project/user/plugins/form/classes/form.php"
line : 552
message : "Undefined index: type"
type : "Whoops\Exception\ErrorException"
```

Code that generate the form:

```
{% set scope = scope ?: 'data.' %}
{% set multipart = '' %}
{% set method = form.method|upper|default('POST') %}

{% set action = form.action ? base_url ~ form.action : base_url ~ page.route 
 ~ uri.params %}

{% if (action == base_url_relative) %}
{% set action = base_url_relative ~ '/' ~ page.slug %}
{% endif %}

<form name="{{ form.name }}"
  action="{{ action }}"
  method="{{ method }}"{{ multipart }}
  {% if form.id %}id="{{ form.id }}"{% endif %}
  {% block form_classes %}
  {% if form.classes %}class="{{ form.classes }}"{% endif %}
  {% endblock %}
>

<div class="stay_tune pure-u-4-5 pure-g">
{% block inner_markup_fields_start %}{% endblock %}

<div class="group pure-u-3-5 email_register_container">
  <input name="email" type="email" required>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label class="label">Email</label>
</div>

{% include "forms/fields/formname/formname.html.twig" %}

{% block inner_markup_fields_end %}{% endblock %}

{% block inner_markup_buttons_start %}
<div class="pure-u-2-5 register_button_container">
{% endblock %}
{{dump(form)}}
  <p class="message_form">{{form.process[1].message}}</p>
  <button type="submit" class="register_button" name="button">
{{form.button.value}}</button>
{% block inner_markup_buttons_end %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
</div>

{{ nonce_field('form', 'form-nonce')|raw }}
</form>
```

I did check permission and clear cache without sucess, I'm out of ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The file `/user/plugins/form/classes/form.php` at line `552` contains this line of code `if ($field['type'] == 'checkbox') {` which means: if the field type is 'checkbox' then...

Your error "Undefined index: type" (which is stricly correlated to arrays) states that he cannot find and index named 'type' in `$field` array.

This piece of code (line 552) is also executed in a function called `post()`.

So, I can deduce that: while checking your fields after the post request one of them doesn't have the `type` property.

To solve the problem you could check your generated HTML output (inspect element) on the form and find the wrong formatted input.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like there is a problem with your checkbox.

Can you post your form definition?

Comment: I don't have any checkbox ! I add the code that generate the form.